# What is the best way to listen for complex object changes, using ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

The complex object has a collection of objects for example

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    public string Name { get;set;}

    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyClasses {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to create an observable and know when one of the MyClasses collection items has changed (Name or Description).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs, especially **Using Change Tracking** section](http://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/lists/index.html).

In short:

1) use `ReactiveList` instead of an `ObservableCollection`, and set `ChangeTrackingEnabled` to true:

```
// in MyViewModel constructor
this.MyClasses = new ReactiveList<MyClass>()
{
    ChangeTrackingEnabled = true,
};
```

2) `MyClass` should raise `PropertyChanged` events. The easiest way to do that is to make it derive from ReactiveObject:

```
public class MyClass : ReactiveObject
{ 
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value); 
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _description, value); 
    }
}
```

3) Use `ItemChanged` property of your list

```
this.MyClasses.ItemChanged.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Changed!"))
```